# Python equivalent of R's rnbinom parametrized with mu

Tags: python, r, numpy

R has a [negative binomial function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html) that can be parameterized with `mu` rather than a probability (e.g., a float >= 0 and <=1). I am trying to replicate this distribution:

```
rnbinom(1000,size=0.3,mu=15)
```

in Python. From what I can see, [Numpy's negative binomial function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.negative_binomial.html) only allows a probability. Also, I am unclear as to what the `size` parameter would be in Numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the parameters that you passed to `rnbinom`:

```
In [131]: num_samples = 10000

In [132]: size = 0.3

In [133]: mu = 15
```

As explained in the R documentation that you linked to, you can compute the probability as follows:

```
In [134]: prob = size/(size + mu)
```

The first two arguments of `numpy.random.negative_binomial` correspond to the `size` and `prob` arguments of the R functions.  The third argument of `negative_binomial` is the number of samples.  (Be careful--numpy calls this argument `size`; it refers to the size of the sample to generate.  All the numpy random functions take a `size` argument.)

```
In [135]: sample = np.random.negative_binomial(size, prob, num_samples)
```

The mean of the sample should be close to 15.

```
In [136]: sample.mean()
Out[136]: 14.9032
```